# Configuring WooCommerce on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, npm, woocommerce

I am trying to setup WooCommerce following the steps in link below:
[https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/How-to-set-up-WooCommerce-development-environment][1]

I have reach the step where I run the command

```
npm run build
```

and I get error npm

> ERR! missing script: build

my package.json fie is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "woocommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "=== WooCommerce ===\r Contributors: automattic, mikejolley, jameskoster, claudiosanches, kloon, rodrigosprimo, peterfabian1000, vedjain\r Tags: ecommerce, e-commerce, store, sales, sell, shop, cart, checkout, downloadable, downloads, payments, paypal, storefront, stripe, woo commerce, woo\r Requires at least: 4.9\r Tested up to: 5.2\r Requires PHP: 5.6\r Stable tag: 3.8.0\r License: GPLv3\r License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nadersam/woocommerce.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nadersam/woocommerce/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nadersam/woocommerce#readme"
}
```

Appreciate any help about this please.

Comment: when you run that command are you in the WooCommerce directory?

Comment: yes and the package.json is there

Comment: any help about this please?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your package.json you got version "1.0.0" you need the latest version of WooCommerce which at this point in time is "4.8.0", bump your WooCommerce version to 4.8.0 and your package.json should have the build script in it.